# How to prevent submitting form based on text in an html element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I have a form in that I have User Id availability check. So if Id is already in DB it will show a message "Id is already in use". In that case I have to avoid submitting the form. For that my html is as follow,

```
<div>
<label><strong>Teacher Id:</strong></label>
<input type="text" name="teacherId" id="teacherId" placeholder="Enter Teacher Id"  > 
</div><span class="status" id="status"></span>
```

Here span will have the text about availability,

The value to span comes form jquery post call,

```
$.post('<%=request.getContextPath()%>/controller/TeacherIdCheckController',
{'teacherId':teacherId},
 function(data)
 {
$('.status').html(data);
  });
}
```

This works fine, to prevent submitting I wrote javascript function as,

```
function checkTeacherId(){
 alert(" in checkTecherId()");
 var status=$("#status").text();
 alert(status);
 if(status=="Id in use try another")
preventDefault();
 else
return true;

}
```

Everything works fine but this javascript function is not working fine so I cant able to prevent submit in case of Id already exist in DB. So please anyone help me in this.

Comment: Where are you using `checkTeacherId()`?

Comment: I am using it in onclick of submit button.

Comment: like this `<input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Submit" onclick="checkTeacherId();" />`

Comment: Instead of `preventDefault()`, change the line to `return false`

Comment: Give complete information like full html, mainly <form> tag, the attributes set on this tag affects form submit, form validation etc

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just because you need to pass the event in the function's arg:

```
function checkTeacherId(e){ // <---pass the event here
  .....
 if(status=="Id in use try another")
   e.preventDefault(); // and stop it here using dot notation
 else
   return true;
}
```

As per your comment you can pass the event to your function in your `onclick` handler:

```
onclick="checkTeacherId(event);"
```

---

### [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TnPxh/)

---

Okay! As @Sanjeev tried commenting on *best approach* for this work then as you are using jQuery then you can just do this as per best approach like **Unobrusive Javascript** *(removing this inliner scripts just like above posted)*:

```
function checkTeacherId(e){ // <---pass the event here
  .....
 if(status=="Id in use try another")
   e.preventDefault(); // and stop it here using dot notation
 else
   return true;
}


$(function(){
   $('#yourformid').on('submit', function(e){
      checkTeacherId(e);
   });
});
```

---

Use this approach if you want to externalize your scripts as declare the function in global scope and put your event handler in doc ready with `submit` event.

---

### [Updated fiddle with unobtrusive way.](http://jsfiddle.net/TnPxh/1/)

Comment: also it's better to write `return false;` after the `e.preventDefault();`

Comment: no its not working , is this right way of using the fun in btn `<input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Submit" onclick="checkTeacherId();" />`

Comment: @user3599482 you need to pass event in the function within your onclick handler, see the updated answer and a working fiddle there.

Comment: thank u it solved . I have to use `trim`. will u pls tell wht it does?

Comment: @user3599482 `$.trim()` is a jQuery function which removes the extra whitespace at both ends of a string.

Comment: This is not the best or suitable approach for form validation, this might not work correctly in IE legacy browsers. Use native onsubmit Event handler for form validation as it is made solely for this purpose.

Comment: @Sanjeev _best or suitable approach_....Don't you think unobtrusive javascript is the only best approach.

Comment: @Jai : For form validation i don't think onclick handler is best approach, why would anyone not use the native event handler for this work. If it was a normal button type and not submit button then may be using onclick handler would have been fine, but this is not the case here.

Comment: @Sanjeev Ha ha ha! Its okay just post a solution with unobtrusive js and get +1.

Comment: @Sanjeev i think you misunderstood _Unobtrusive Javascript_....See my updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

### Solution as per best practice for form validation:

You have implemented form submit via Submit button and not through js like document.getElementById("myForm").submit();

I don't see any point in using onclick handler on submit button for validation, use the native onsubmit Event Attribute, else you will keep on breaking submit flow.
onsubmit  is made for validating form and stopping form submission if validation fails.
This will work sure shot in all browsers and is the correct approach for form validation

Example:

```
<form action="demo_form.asp" onsubmit="return checkTeacherId()">


function checkTeacherId(){
 var status=$("#status").text();

 if(status==="Id in use try another"){
    return false
 }
 else{
 return true;
 }

}
```